# How can I create a Table in JS with "for loops" filled with numbers 1 to 100

Tags: javascript

I created multiplication table using for loop

now I need to create the same table with numbers 1 to 100 like this one:[table][1]

how do I create this one
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAacu.png

```js
document.write('<table border="3">');
for (var x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
  document.write("<tr>")
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    document.write("<td>" + x * i + "</td>")
  }
  document.write("</td>")
}
document.write("</table>")
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried please?

Comment: document.write('<table border="3">');
        for (var x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
            document.write("<tr>")
            for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                document.write("<td>" + x * i + "</td>")
            }
            document.write("</td>")
        }
        document.write("</table>")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start `x` from 0 (to 10) then the formula of the current cell's number is `x * 10 + i` so for [2,2] cell it would be *1 * 10 + 2*

```js
document.write('<table border="3">');
for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  document.write("<tr>")
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.write("<td>" + (x * 10 + i) + "</td>")
  }
  document.write("</td>")
}
document.write("</table>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into your code and seems like logic inside your for loop is not correct.

I am posting a working code logic for this, I hope this is what you need.

```js
document.write('<table border="3">');
for (var x = 1; x <= 100; x += 10) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (let i = x; i <= x + 9; i++) {
    document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
  }
  document.write("</td>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```